# Small details are lost on 3D printing

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I want to make a key chain of a cartoon character,I modeled it but when i exported the model and inserted it in the slicer software i had problems with details like the eyes and the outline of the character what should i do?
[image]
[image]I don't know if this is a modeling problem or a printing problem thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't see the problem, but then I don't know the slicing software. Is it the blue lines going across your model? Also, a picture of your model in Wireframe mode (`Z`) in Blender is always helpful, as it lets us see how your model is put together.

Comment: Most likely an issue with the model details being to small for the printer.

Comment: The slicer seems to be Cura imho. Did you scale it in the slicer, too? That often brings too little features to be printed...

Comment: Yes it is Cura and i did scale it but i scaled it up not down so i thought that wouldn't be a problem

Comment: I would try to use measurement units in blender, then scale it (in blender) until it has the desired scale (I guess the X,Y, Z size shown in the bottom image... then, you can let blender show the size of the smaller details, and compare that to the minimum feature size that your printer can print. You can also use 3d print toolbox budled addon to check your mesh, anyway I think this is just a minimum feature size issue... unless cura is wronlgy configured for your printer, of course

Comment: How can i make blender show me the size of the smaller details